# Удаление пользователя

Tags: php

Имею php код, который выводит на страницу всех пользователей из БД

```
<?php include("db_connect.php");                         
    $sql= "SELECT * FROM `users`";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error() ."<br/>". $sql);
    $table = "<table border=0 width=100%>";
    $table .= "<td id='headers'>".'№'."</td>";
    $table .= "<td id='headers'>".'Имя пользователя'."</td>";
    $table .= "<td id='headers'>".'ФИО'."</td>";
    $count = 1;

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        $table .= "<tr>\n";

        $table .= "<td>".$count."</td>";
        $table .= "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
        $table .= "<td>".$row['fio']."</td>";
        $table .= "<td id='settings'><img src='images/delete.png'></img></td>";

        $table .= "</tr>\n";
        $count = $count + 1;
    }

    $table .= "</table>\n";

    // Выводим заполненую таблицу на экран
    echo $table;                         
?>
```

Выводится картинка (удаления). Каким образом можно осуществить выполнение php (удаления) кода по нажатию на нее. Или каким другим способом это организовать?

Comment: У тега img нет парного закрывающегося

    неверно
    <img src='images/delete.png'></img>

    верно
    <img src='images/delete.png' />

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
// предположим, что твой скрипт называется user.php

// до вывода таблицы пользователей
if (isset($_GET['action']) && 'delete' == $_GET['action'] && !empty($_GET['name'])) {
    // тут через SQL удалить из таблицы users пользователя с именем $_GET['name']
    // например, DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `name` = 'вася'
}

// далее вывести таблицу пользователей

// ...
// в коде, который выводит строки таблицы, заменить строку
$table .= '<td id="settings"><a href="user.php?action=delete&name=' . rawurlencode($row['name']) . '><img src="images/delete.png"/></a></td>';
// ...
```

Comment: Вместо $_GET['name'] rawurlencode($row['name']) лучше использовать $_GET['id'] - $row['id']

Comment: Согласен, но я не телепат и структуру таблицы угадать не могу.

Comment: Все равно спасибо огромное за помощь!

Comment: Только ошибка:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in блаблабла/users.php on line 43

Как раз, где я заменил строчку в таблице.

Comment: Сам разобрался)

Comment: Это я кавычки не правильно расставил. Я уже исправил